# Visual Studio .sln runner - Octopus Packaging - Append to package ID string not working

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am using TeamCity with a Visual Studio (.sln) build step.  In this build step I have the "Run Octopack" setting enabled and the package version set to my team city build number.

I would like to include a specific string in each produced package id and it would seem the 'Append to package ID' setting available in the build step would be the best/easiest way to achieve this.  However any string I include here never shows up in the produced .nupkg files.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of this setting or is there additional requirements to use this field?

Comment: What version of Octopack do you have installed in the project?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd I am using OctoPack v2.0.26

Comment: This parameter was only added in v3 - https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack/commit/c48133c7f10ed3e8dd9fcfc13e499446170f60cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use this functionality you'll need to upgrade the OctoPack version to at least 3.0.6

```
Install-Package OctoPack -Version 3.0.6
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that is what I was missing!